# Does a antivirus scan the RAM for virus detection?

Tags: anti-virus

Does a antivirus scan the RAM for virus detection?I am using a Mcafee, i don't know whether it's relevant, or maybe every virus works the same mechanism?

Answer (score 2):

A virus is a program, either on its own or attached to a legitimate program.  In order for programs to execute (run), programs have to be loaded into RAM.  Anti virus programs will typically scan the programs that are running, as well as scan files on your hard drive.  A virus that is never executed, will not load into RAM, and therefore not be a danger to your computer.